# Getting data from joins in Zend 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a join in Zend. In my model I have

```
$select->join('properties', 'properties.OID = advertised_properties.TenancyProperty', array(), 'left');
```

TenancyProperty is the foreign key which is OID in the properties table.

In my view I can access rows from advertised_properties like this (using pagination)

```
foreach ($this->paginator as $rentals) : ?>
.....
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($rentals->ColumnInAdvertised_Properties);?>
```

but if I try and access rows from the joined table (properties) using

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($rentals->ColumnInProperties);?>
```

I do not get the data. Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong and why I do not get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out! I was missing the values I need in the array like this

```
$select->join('properties', 'properties.OID = advertised_properties.TenancyProperty', array('Column1fromTable' , 'Column2fromTable'), 'left');
```